# Java download file using a byte[]

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I have web-service method which returns a `byte[]`, so I did this to force the download of the returned file

```java
 final byte[] content = axisService.getWebFileContent(pieceJointe.getVlidnlfy());

 if (content != null) {

   final Map<String, Object> lrFile = new HashMap<>(2);
   lrFile.put("CONTENT", content);
   lrFile.put("MIMETYPE", "application/octet-stream");
   response.reset();
   response.resetBuffer();
   response.setContentType("application/force-download");
   response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
       "attachment; filename=\"" + pieceJointe.getLbnompcj() + "\"");// fileName);
   response.getOutputStream().write((byte[]) lrFile.get("CONTENT"));
   response.setContentLength(((byte[]) lrFile.get("CONTENT")).length);
   response.getOutputStream().close();
   response.flushBuffer();
}
```

but it doesn't work and I don't see any error on my console. Do I need to add an additional configuration to my response object ?

Comment: *but it doesn't work and i dont have any error in my console* — What's the error and how is the code supposed to work? Could you please edit your question and add more information?

Comment: Hello , 
 this code is used to force the  donwload  of the file into my browser but nothing happens after the execution of this code

Comment: To exclude the most common beginner's mistake: are you using ajax to hit the "web service"?

Comment: yes i'm using ajax to call my method

Comment: OK, there's nothing wrong with your servlet. The problem is because you're using ajax instead of a simple `window.location=servletUrl`. Next time unit-test your servlet (without ajax). You should have noticed that your code actually worked just fine. See the abovelinked dupe for some solutions/alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

you are setting your content Length after writing the output.

```
  response.getOutputStream().write((byte[]) lrFile.get("CONTENT"));
  response.setContentLength(((byte[]) lrFile.get("CONTENT")).length);
```

to

```
 response.setContentLength((long) lrFile.get("CONTENT").length);
 response.getOutputStream().write((byte[]) lrFile.get("CONTENT"));
```

Comment: same problem even after doing this

Comment: does your " lrFile.get("CONTENT").length" return >0 ?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not `filename*=` in the content disposiition, the file name should not contain special characters.

You still should not have written to the output (neither `getOutputSteam()` or `getOutputWriter()`).

```
   response.setContentType("application/force-download");
   response.setContentLength(content.length);
   //response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
   String filename = URLEncoder.encode(pieceJointe.getLbnompcj(), "UTF-8");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

   response.getOutputStream().write(content);
   response.getOutputStream().close();
```

At the moment I cannot test the code for content disposition. So read at the reference.
It could be something like:

```
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'" + filename);
```

`reset` should not be done, `resetBuffer` is more a hack should something alredy have been written but still reside in the buffer.

Comment: i resolved the problem by creating a form and using the submit action to execute the request

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you s3Client getObject as byte[] fileContent.

```
byte[] fileContent = s3Client.getObject(imagesBucketName, documentsFolderName, metadata.getFileName());
        resource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent));

FileResponse fileResponse = new FileResponse();
    fileResponse.setInputStreamResource(resource);
    fileResponse.setMimeType(metadata.getContentType());
    fileResponse.setFileSize(metadata.getFileSize());

@GetMapping("/logo/{spaceId}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getCompanyLogo(@PathVariable("spaceId") Integer spaceId)
        throws FileDownloadException, InvalidInputException {
    FileResponse fileResponse = companySpaceService.downloadCompanyLogo();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(fileResponse.getFileSize())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fileResponse.getMimeType()))
            .body(fileResponse.getInputStreamResource());
}
```